# How to fetch data in Oracle database and use it in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, database, oracle, selenium-webdriver

I have two test cases.

First Test Case: Create a user. Once the user is created, the info gets stored in the database.(i.e account number, username, password, first name, last name etc)

Second Test Case: Login as a User.

Once the first test case has been passed, how can I fetch the data from the db (e.g. select * from created_user) and use it in my second test case.

For example: I would like to fetch the username and password from the database, and use it in my second test case when i'm on the login page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the database in tests of a browser based interface? Just mock the responses using whatever you are using to perform the tests and do not involve the database in tests of your front-end.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you do is if you really want to verify the data in the database, do that at the end of the first test case.  Use clean data each time so you don't have to worry about bad data.

What if your second test case fails because the data in the first test case is no good? Then you've failed the second test case because of bad data not bad functionality.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want to login into the application with the test data that you entered during creation of the user.
For that you need to make a program which connects you with your db.

Flow of your suit:

First Step: Create a user. Once the user is created, the info gets stored in the database

Second Step : create a connection class, get all the details into variables.

Third Step : Pass those variables *test data* into your scrip.

That's all.

Connection class :

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
//step1 load the driver class  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","password");  

//step3 create the statement object  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

//step4 execute query  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from created_user");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

//step5 close the connection object  
con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

you can pass rs.getInt(1) into a var. and use this variable as your test data.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Junit Test called LoginTest, and in this Test, it contains two testcase, the first one is create user test case , the second one is login test case

```
// make sure the createUserTest is test first
@FixMethodOrder(value = MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class LoginTest {

  // User that created in the createUserTest
  private User user = null;

  @AfterClass
  public void clear() {
    if (user != null) {
       someDbLogic.delete(user)
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void createUserTest() {
    // create user and save it to db
    user = new User();
    // save to db
    someDbLogic.save(user)
  }

  @Test
  public void loginTest() {
    // get loginId and password from user and perform login action by selenium
    String loginId = user.getLogin();
    String password = user.getPassword();

    // perform login
  }
}
```

In junit, the @AfterClass will be invoke after all the test cases have been run, then we can delete the user data there.

I hope this can help you a bit.